# Sorting columns of multiindex dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a very large multi index dataframe with about 500 columns and each column has 2 sub columns.

The dataframe `df` looks as:

```
                  B2                  B5             B3
bkt              A1      A2           A2      A1     Z2      C1
Date                                                                        
2019-06-11       0.8     0.2          -6.0    -0.8   -4.1    -0.6    
2019-06-12       0.8     0.2          -6.9    -1.6   -5.3    -1.2    

df.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[['B2', 'B5', 'B3', .....], ['A1', 'A2' ......]],
           labels=[[1, 1, ....], [1, 0, ....]],
           names=[None, 'bkt'])
```

I am trying to sort only the column names and keep the values as it is within each column to get the following desired output:

```
                 B2                  B3             B5
bkt              A1      A2          C1      Z2     A1      A2
Date                                                                        
2019-06-11       ..
2019-06-12       ..
```

`..` represents the values from the original dataframe. I just didn't retype them.

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [.8, .2, -6., -.8, -4.1, -.6],
    [.8, .2, -6.9, -1.6, -5.3, -1.2]
],
    pd.date_range('2019-06-11', periods=2, name='Date'),
    pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
        'B2 B2 B5 B5 B3 B3'.split(),
        'A1 A2 A2 A1 Z2 C1'.split()
    ], names=[None, 'bkt'])
)
```

Comment: sort_index(level=0, axis=1)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and assign it back

```
df.columns=df.sort_index(axis=1,level=[0,1],ascending=[True,False]).columns
```

And from piR , we do not need create the copy of df, just do modification with the columns

```
df.columns=df.columns.sort_values(ascending=[True, False])
```

Comment: How do I modify the above code so that it is sorted ascending on level "B2                  B5             B3" and descending on "A1      A2           A2      A1     Z2      C1" ? I didnt want to start another post for this.

Comment: Do this to avoid creating a new dataframe and only focus on sorting the index itself.  `df.columns = df.columns.sort_values(ascending=[True, False])`

Comment: @piRSquared that is true :-)

Comment: I am always intrigued by the clever ways your guys solve convoluted stuff here :)

Comment: I am not sure @piRSquared solution works however. Your original solution does work.

Comment: your approach works and @piRSquared 's does not.

Comment: also, this only rearranges to columns and does not move the column data along with it. To do that it should be `df.columns=df.sort_index(axis=1,level=[0,1],ascending=[True,False]).columns`

Comment: WARNING if you apply this: this move columns header but *not the values inside* ! It only rearrange header, not moving the values!! That is usually not what you want...

Answer (score 6):

This should be done using `sort_index` to move both the column names and data:

```
df.sort_index(axis=1, level=[0, 1], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
```